# Chain of Responsibility Design Pattern confusion on how it works

Tags: c#

```
Below code is from the article in CodeProject website. It is an example that explains **Code of responsibility design pattern**. Here is the link  "https://www.codeproject.com/articles/494241/understanding-and-implementing-chain-of-responsibi"
```

I am not able to understand when **tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 15));** line gets executed in the **main** method and LeaveApplied method on Supervisor property is called **Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);** where **this** is pointing to the object of type ProjectLeader class inside **void TeamLeader_onLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l)** method then how called method in the base class Employee **public void LeaveApplied(Employee s, Leave leave)** first parameter **Employee s** keeps pointing to object of type TeamLeader. How is this possible? Shouldn't **Employee s** be pointing to the object of type **ProjectLeader**. Please help me to understand how this happened? Thanks for your help.

```
 public abstract class Employee
        {
            // Every employee will have a supervisor
            protected Employee supervisor;

            // Event mechanism to know whenever a leave has been applied
            public delegate void OnLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l);
            public event OnLeaveApplied onLeaveApplied = null;

            // This will invoke events when the leave will be applied
            // i.e. the actual item will be handed over to the hierarchy of
            // concrete handlers.
            public void LeaveApplied(Employee s, Leave leave)
            {
                if (onLeaveApplied != null)
                {
                    onLeaveApplied(this, leave);
                }
            }

            // This is the function which concrete handlers will use to take 
            // action, if they are able to take actions.
            public abstract void ApproveLeave(Leave leave);

            // getter to get the supervisor of current employee
            public Employee Supervisor

            {
                get
                {
                    return supervisor;
                }
                set
                {
                    supervisor = value;
                }
            }

            // Using this we can apply for leave
            public void ApplyLeave(Leave l)
            {
                LeaveApplied(this, l);
            }
        }
        public class TeamLeader : Employee
        {
            // team leas can only approve up to 7 days of leave
            const int MAX_LEAVES_CAN_APPROVE = 10;

            // in constructor we will attach the event handler that
            // will check if this employee can process or he needs to
            // pass on to next employee
            public TeamLeader()
            {
                this.onLeaveApplied += new OnLeaveApplied(TeamLeader_onLeaveApplied);
            }

            // in this function we will check if this employee can 
            // process or he needs to pass on to next employee
            void TeamLeader_onLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l)
            {
                // check if we can process this request
                if (l.NumberOfDays < MAX_LEAVES_CAN_APPROVE)
                {
                    // process it on our level only
                    ApproveLeave(l);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if we cant process pass on to the supervisor 
                    // so that he can process
                    if (Supervisor != null)
                    {
                        Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we can process lets show the output
            public override void ApproveLeave(Leave leave)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LeaveID: {0} Days: {1} Approver: {2}",
                    leave.LeaveID, leave.NumberOfDays, "Team Leader");
            }
        }
        class ProjectLeader : Employee
        {
            const int MAX_LEAVES_CAN_APPROVE = 20;

            // in constructor we will attach the event handler that
            // will check if this employee can process or he needs to
            // pass on to next employee
            public ProjectLeader()
            {
                this.onLeaveApplied += new OnLeaveApplied(ProjectLeader_onLeaveApplied);
            }

            // in this function we will check if this employee can 
            // process or he needs to pass on to next employee
            void ProjectLeader_onLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l)
            {
                // check if we can process this request
                if (l.NumberOfDays < MAX_LEAVES_CAN_APPROVE)
                {
                    // process it on our level only
                    ApproveLeave(l);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if we cant process pass on to the supervisor 
                    // so that he can process
                    if (Supervisor != null)
                    {
                        Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we can process lets show the output
            public override void ApproveLeave(Leave leave)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LeaveID: {0} Days: {1} Approver: {2}",
                    leave.LeaveID, leave.NumberOfDays, "Project Leader");
            }

        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // lets create employees 
                TeamLeader tl = new TeamLeader();
                ProjectLeader pl = new ProjectLeader();
                HR hr = new HR();

                // Now lets set the hierarchy of employees
                tl.Supervisor = pl;
                pl.Supervisor = hr;

                // Now lets apply 5 day leave my TL
                tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 5));

                // Now lets apply 15 day leave my TL
                tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 15));

                // Now lets apply 25 day leave my TL
                tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 25));

                // Now lets apply 35 day leave my TL
                tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 35));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: First, name of pattern is ```Chain of Responsibility```, not "code". Second - please, remove all code which is not related to your question and point which lines (including line numbers) confuses you. Because it is not clear what you asking about since there 3 different ```Supervisor.LeaveApplied``` lines here.

Answer (score 0):

`tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 15));` Not sure what you don't understand here, it get executed after `tl.ApplyLeave(new Leave(Guid.NewGuid(), 5));`

Supervisors are declared in the `Main()`:

```
tl.Supervisor = pl;
pl.Supervisor = hr;
```

So this `Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);` gets called whenever this condition is met:

```
// check if we can process this request
if (l.NumberOfDays < MAX_LEAVES_CAN_APPROVE)
{
    // process it on our level only
    ApproveLeave(l);
}
else
{
    // if we cant process pass on to the supervisor 
    // so that he can process
    if (Supervisor != null)
    {
        Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);
    }
}
```

`public void LeaveApplied(Employee s, Leave leave)`, yes `Employee s` is an object of `TeamLeader` at first however, look at the above conditional statement, `Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l);` supervisor calls the method because leave is greater than 10 days, thus it's `ProjectLeader`

Also, you would have much better understanding if you debug it by stepping through the code yourself and see how each method is called.

**EDIT**

After looking at it again, there really is no need for `public void LeaveApplied(Employee s, Leave leave)` it should of been just `public void LeaveApplied(Leave leave)` Since inside of that method is:

```
if (onLeaveApplied != null)
{
    onLeaveApplied(this, leave);
}
```

So I don't see the point of `Employee s`.

Comment: I got this part but was not able to understand after we call LeaveApplied method on Object of type ProjectLeader Supervisor.LeaveApplied(this, l)" then how come in the called method that is present in the base class Employee "public void LeaveApplied(Employee s, Leave leave)" still have parameter "s" pointing to TeamLeader object type?

Comment: @MuskanB if you look at my edit, there's really no need for that parameter, you can remove it, it doesn't add any value to the `method`.

Comment: I totally agree with you we can remove this parameter as it is not required here. But still, want to understand why this parameter value does not get modified. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MuskanB It doesn't get modified because `this` keyword is still referring to `TeamLeader`.

Comment: No, it is referring to ProjectLeader.

Comment: @MuskanB How so? Do a Console.WriteLine(s); you will see the result. `void TeamLeader_onLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l)` is called from object type of `TeamLeader` correct? Thus `this` keyword is `TeamLeader`

Comment: Thanks again ...you are correct TeamLeader_onLeaveApplied(Employee e, Leave l) is called from object type of TeamLeader but does not "this" keyword started pointing to ProjectLeader when Supervisor.LeaveApplied (this, l) line got executed.

Comment: No, `this` refers to whatever object your in... So if you pass in `this` from `ProjectLeader` then that `this` is `ProjectLeader`. `Supervisor.LeaveApplied (this, l)` doesn't change `this` object, it is passing in the current object you're currently in...